# Virtualbox: connect from guest OS to host's OS apache virtual hosts

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache-http-server

I know that it is possible to access host machine's localhost using gateway's IP 10.0.0.2, but I have several hosts I need to access from guest.
Example of hosts-file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.10  my-domain-one.tld
127.0.0.11  my-domain-two.tld
...
127.0.0.20  my-domain-ten.tld
```

My host OS is Win8, guest - Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Apache virtual hosts on host Web server.  Access each  vhost with a port.  Then type host ip followed by port,  to access a vhost  from guest machine.

Comment: I use Apache hosts on host OS and need to use them on guest OS the same way. Using different ports for each host is too inconvenient...

Comment: I thought, if there is no better way (but I hope there is), I'll share my htdocs directory with guest OS and run Apache there...